# protobuf backward compatibility

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, compatibility

The following is overly simplified version of my protobuf messages:

```
message Item {
  string attribute0 = 1;
}

message Group {
  string name = 1;
  repeated Item = 2;  
}
```

And, a quite sizable software has been already implemented and running, using the protobuf message. The messages are sent by a client tool and consumed by the server.

I am about to update the server, and release a new client. The thing is that we still have to support the old client; the old client should be able to send the messages to the new server, and get the same result from the server.

And, I am planning to add fields to `Item`. Would it break compatibility with `Group`? My understanding is that as long as I do not change old numberings in `Item` and add optional fields only, the client sending `Item` will still work. However, what if the client was sending `Group`? Is `Item` now regarded as a different type so effectively the type of one field inside `Group` changed?

Comment: Adding new fields is backward-compatible (assuming that it's safe for the older client to ignore these fields). That's one of the main points of protobuf design. The protobuf parser safely skips any fields it doesn't know about, precisely for the reason of maintaining forward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

> And, I am planning to add fields to Item. Would it break compatibility with Group? My understanding is that as long as I do not change old numberings in Item and add optional fields only, the client sending Item will still work.

That is correct.

> However, what if the client was sending Group? Is Item now regarded as a different type so effectively the type of one field inside Group changed?

Protobuf has no concept of types in the encoded data, it has only tag numbers. You could change the names of your types to entirely different, as long as the tag numbers in both messages stay the same.